# Paragraph child element of <details> tag is not pushing down below html elements after applying CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an accordion using plain html and CSS.

and for that I am using `<details>` html tag.

It is working fine before applying CSS, that means when we open first accordion, the rest elements automatically moves down to show the content.

But when style is applied then no longer push the elements.

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
     Click and Know
    </h1>
    
    <details class="accordion">
      <summary>About Paris</summary>
      <p>Paris, France's capital, is a major European city and a global center for art, fashion, gastronomy and culture. Its 19th-century cityscape is crisscrossed by wide boulevards and the River Seine. Beyond such landmarks as the Eiffel Tower and the 12th-century, Gothic Notre-Dame cathedral, the city is known for its cafe culture and designer boutiques along the Rue du Faubourg Saint-Honoré.</p>
    </details>
    <details class="accordion">
      <summary>About Amsterdam</summary>
      <p>Amsterdam is the Netherlands’ capital, known for its artistic heritage, elaborate canal system and narrow houses with gabled facades, legacies of the city’s 17th-century Golden Age. Its Museum District houses the Van Gogh Museum, works by Rembrandt and Vermeer at the Rijksmuseum, and modern art at the Stedelijk. Cycling is key to the city’s character, and there are numerous bike paths.</p>
    </details>
    <details class="accordion">
      <summary>About India</summary>
      <p>India, officially the Republic of India, is a country in South Asia. It is the second-most populous country, the seventh-largest country by land area, and the most populous democracy in the world.</p>
    </details>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
details {
  width: 500px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #303030;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
details > summary {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
details > summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}

details > summary::after {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}

details[open] > summary::after {
  content: "-";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}

details > p {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #303030;
  color: white;
}
```

If you Remove styling and check, everything works as expected, but I want to achieve the same thing with styling.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is just a problem I can see, it's caused by `details {height: 35px;}`.

Change it to `min-height`.

Comment: thanks pavel it is working fine, can you explain what was the issue in your words

Comment: It's easy. When you have an element with 35px height (fix height), what you expect from nested content with height eg. 150px? This text has been overflowed, notning more.